# "NeumorphicToggle" for Flutter doesn't work

Tags: flutter, toggle

I would appreciate a lot if somebody could give example code when NeumorphicToggle widget described here https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_neumorphic/latest/ works. OnChanged event doesnt "move" the buttons in interface.

Answer (score 0):

Found out answer myself. After setState() you update the variable but if inside class the same variable has initial value assigned, after setState() it becomes assigned again.

Solution: just move variable you want to change with toggle outside the class.